# how to measure IP bandwidth in pass through mode in linux?

Tags: linux, monitoring, router, bandwidth, openwrt

I want to measure the IP bandwidth in pass through mode. Please find the attached picture for configuration and my question also.

If there is no solution with OpenWRT, I need any alternative solution considering this as simple linux box.

I would be very much grateful if someone can provide the procedure to complete the talk.

Thanks in Advance friends.
[image]

I am aware of IPerf but not fully sure upto what extent Iperf can support this problem, If you can put some light on it...

Comment: This should probably go on Superuser or ServerFault. Guessing Superuser due to hardware?

Comment: Should I put the same question in the superuser? Or this will be automatically directed to superuser?

Comment: It has been sent to the moderators for migration, and if they agree they will move it over shortly :)